# List of characters that will be encoded for List/Library column names

Tags: javascript, encoding

For a javascript based SharePoint application, I noticed that the internal name of columns with spaces are encoded.  When updating these fields using the Javascript Rest API my data needs to include the field names as encoded values.  For example, a column with the name "Item Status" is encoded to "Item_x0020_Status".  Is there a list of all characters that encoded to these unicode values?  Or the inverse (list of characters not encoded)?

Ultimately I would like to build some sort of function or regular expression that captures and replaces encoded characters with their respective values.

Comment: This might help: https://n8d.at/blog/encode-and-decode-field-names-from-display-name-to-internal-name/

Comment: This was a good example.  Though I have a question as to why you would use 'escape' instead of 'encodeURICompoent'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a little more complicated than that. The internal name, set when the column is created, isn't always the encoded value of the current display name.

If the display name hasn't been changed, you are right, 'Item Status' has an internal name of 'Internal_x0020_Status'.

Most special characters not alphabetic/numeric will be encoded. If you can ensure your list column display names match the internal name things might work.

However, there are some gotchas.

1. If a field is created with a beginning number - example '4th
   Quarter', the internal name would be _x0034_th_x0020_Quarter. Also, I've seen posts where a beginning letter is encoded, for what reason I don't know.
2. Also, a field's display name can be changed - what might have an
   internal name of 'Item_x0020_Status' might very well have a display
   name of 'Current Item Status', so if you encoded the display name it
   would still be incorrect.
3. Another issue - an internal field name might have a limit of 32 characters,
   so the internal name might be truncated.

You'd have to account for all of that besides the physical encoding (which could be done with an XML conversion function.

To be totally generic, you'd have to use the REST api to get the internal names you need, then use those to do your update. Or if you use SPServices you can use SPService calls to `$().SPServices.SPGetStaticFromDisplay` http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/utilities/SPGetStaticFromDisplay.html

Comment: I am trying to create a column in a SharePoint list from a Power Automate flow using the `Send an HTTP request to SharePoint` action, and when I specify the `InternalName` as `Task50` and the `Title` as `Task 50 - Title`, it creates a column with this internal name: 
 `Task_x0020_50_x0020__x002d__x002`.   I believe that numbers are allowed in internal names, so I don't know why the `50` value is being encoded :(.